# Invoking a jRuby gem from inside an MRI ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Is there a way to use a locally packaged jruby gem inside a ruby on rails application that uses MRI?

I currently use the following:

`platform :jruby do
  gem 'my_gem', path: "path_to_my_gem"
end`

and I am not sure if it works. The gem is a bench of rake tasks, which I can't see when I run rake -T.

Any ideas?

Comment: That just tells Bundler to load "my_gem" when the environment is JRuby. You cannot load a JRuby gem on MRI.

Comment: Yes, I think that's clear. Now is it possible to switch to jruby when I invoke those rake tasks?

Comment: If you have something like Rbenv or RVM you can switch your environment when you run the rake tasks.

Comment: But the tasks are not loaded with Rails. That's currently the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no such thing as a jruby gem per se. it's the `platform` that you configure your gem to run on in the gem specification.

this is what bundler uses to split up groups so that you can include platform specific gems.

in the case of jruby, the platform is the JVM. so if you want to invoke tasks that require a java integration you need to run them with jruby.

so the short answer is: NO

the long answer is that there are several ways to invoke stuff from MRI.

you could shell out and run jruby via the commandline to issue a command on that gem.

you could use the ruby java bridge to interact with java directly, maybe even load the gem in some weird kind of way through a ScriptContainer.

Comment: Yes, the gem is regular ruby that packages some tasks that are run with jruby. This is what I am actually doing, load the gem and just shell out to run the task, or call ```system `jruby task.rb` ```. But the problem so far is that the tasks are not loaded as part of my rails application.

Comment: they will never be unless you start rails with jruby.